# How do you say 'in doing so' in German?

Tags: english-to-german

How do you say 'in doing so' in German?

> Reflecting images of an emerging China, all 91 grand houses of Imperial Summer Palaces were well designed by world's top-ranking architects. Furthermore, **in doing so**, architects selected quality stone material from Europe and took their inspiration from the Chinese imperial gradens.

My attempt is:

> Reflektierende Bilder aufkommmenden China, alle die 91 schönen Häuser imperialischen Sommerpälaste wurden von behrümsten Archichtekten. Ausserdem **wenn man so verfährt**, Architekten haben Qualtäatsteinenmaterailien aus Europa und haben  aus dem chinesischen imperialischen Gärten.

Comment: Your attempt looks like a Google translation. This service isn't really helpful with complicated sentences like these.

Comment: I submit that the original is very poorly worded to begin with. "Furthermore, in doing so" makes no sense there. There is only one possible antedecent, "design well". And you don't select quality stone and take inspiration from gardens by designing well. If anything, it's exactly the other way round. And the "furthermore" just has no business being there at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My translation:

*Das Bild eines aufstrebenden Chinas beschwörend, wurden alle 91 Gebäude (?) der kaiserlichen (?) Sommerpaläste von weltweit führenden Architekten gestaltet. **Dabei** verwendeten die Architekten hochwertiges Gestein aus Europa und ließen sich von den chinesischen kaiserlichen Gärten inspirieren.*

So in this case *in doing so* can be translated as *dabei*.

Answer (score 3):

There's no need to translate *in doing so* word by word. Just use "dadurch", "dabei", "somit", "auf diese Weise" or similar as appropriate.